rangeSelectionChanged Ag Grid Dash Plotly
I want to use the Range Selection feature using Ag Grid in Dash Plotly, but this code doesn't work:
import dash
from dash import html
from dash import dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_ag_grid

app = dash.Dash(__name__)


app.layout = html.Div([
    dash_ag_grid.AgGrid(
        id='ag-grid',
        columnDefs=[
            {'headerName': 'Make', 'field': 'make'},
            {'headerName': 'Model', 'field': 'model'},
            {'headerName': 'Price', 'field': 'price'}
        ],
        rowData=[
            {'make': 'Toyota', 'model': 'Corolla', 'price': 20000},
            {'make': 'Ford', 'model': 'Focus', 'price': 25000},
            {'make': 'BMW', 'model': 'X5', 'price': 60000}
        ],
        enableEnterpriseModules=True,
        dashGridOptions={
            "enableRangeSelection":True,
            "enableRangeSelectionParams":{
                'onRangeSelectionChanged': 'onRangeSelectionChanged'
            }
        }
    ),
    html.Div(id='output')
])

@app.callback(
    Output('output', 'children'),
    [Input('ag-grid', 'rangeSelectionChanged')],
)
def update_output(rangeSelection):
    print(rangeSelection)
    return rangeSelection

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)

I want to select some cells and receive those cells in the range I selected

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

rangeSelectionChanged is not an option in Dash Ag Grid, you will need to either add a custom event listener or use one of the Grid Options to trigger a custom JS function like copying the select range to the clipboard will trigger the JS function to execute.
app.py
import dash
from dash import html
from dash import dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_ag_grid

app = dash.Dash(__name__)


app.layout = html.Div([
    dash_ag_grid.AgGrid(
        id='ag-grid',
        columnDefs=[
            {'headerName': 'Make', 'field': 'make'},
            {'headerName': 'Model', 'field': 'model'},
            {'headerName': 'Price', 'field': 'price'}
        ],
        rowData=[
            {'make': 'Toyota', 'model': 'Corolla', 'price': 20000},
            {'make': 'Ford', 'model': 'Focus', 'price': 25000},
            {'make': 'BMW', 'model': 'X5', 'price': 60000}
        ],
        enableEnterpriseModules=True,
        dashGridOptions={
            "enableRangeSelection": True,
            "processCellForClipboard": {"function": "myFunction(params)"}  # when copied trigger myFunction
        },
    ),
    html.Div(id='output')
])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)

assets/dashAgGridFunctions.js
var dagfuncs = (window.dashAgGridFunctions = window.dashAgGridFunctions || {});


dagfuncs.myFunction = (params) => {
    console.log(params);
};


